# I am trying to pass variables which contain spaces through to a php page via a url

Tags: php, email

The strings are not being passed via the url to the php page if they contain spaces. is it possible to pass strings with spaces through the url?

url code

```
$message = $email_message.'<a href="http://www.example.co.uk/email_feedback/feedback_result.php?name='.$name.'&email_message='.$email_message.'">Click HERE to Activate</a>';
```

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, replace spaces in the URL with `+`. So `?name=John Doe` becomes `?name=John+Doe`.

Comment: What if it also contains `&` or `?` or `=` or any number of other characters?

Comment: @AbraCadaver: Then you would use [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function as suggested by Kisaragi above.

Comment: Yes I know, that was rhetorical.